# Why is it saying "cast string to float is not supported" when I'm not converting any strings to floats?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I run my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import keras

class Output(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(Output, self).__init__(name=name)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.argmax(tf.tensordot(inputs[1], inputs[0], axes=(-1,-1)))


module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-qa/3"

a = tf.keras.Input((), dtype='string')
c = tf.keras.Input((), dtype='string')
q = tf.keras.Input((), dtype='string')
response_e = hub.KerasLayer(module_url, input_shape=[], signature='response_encoder',         
output_key='outputs')({'input': a, 'context': c})
question_e = hub.KerasLayer(module_url, input_shape=[], signature='question_encoder',     
output_key='outputs')(q)
outputs = Output()([response_e, question_e])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[a, c, q], outputs=outputs)

model.predict([tf.constant(['hello','howdy']), tf.constant(['good morning',"How's it going"]), 
tf.constant(['What is an example of a greeting?','How can I say hello?'])])
```

It gives me the error

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
 [[node functional_7/Cast_1 (defined at <ipython-input-12-e1ab62208da7>:14) ]][Op:__inference_predict_function_936411]

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

When the expected output was a tensor of the argmax of the inner product of the two encodings.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a full stack trace.  My guess is that one of your arguments to `model_predict` is a string, where a float is required.  You might check the method documentation.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.